# Remove HTML tags while reading XML data on Android

Tags: android

I am new to working on Android technology. I have to read XML files in which there are HTML tags such as <b> so I have to remove these tags before I display them on screen. If you know any way to remove these before display please help me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure html tags are illegal in XML. And if you're not using valid xml, I don't think any of the built in parsers will work anyway. Or at least they're not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find your answer here:
[How to strip or escape html tags in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502759/how-to-strip-or-escape-html-tags-in-android)

In short Html.fromHtml(stringToEscape).toString()

Answer (score 6):

if you need to strip all the html tags you use the String method `replaceAll("<(.|\n)*?>","");`

Comment: There's a built in method just for that: Html.fromHtml().toString()