# How to strip or escape html tags in Android

Tags: android, strip-tags

PHP has `strip_tags` function which strips HTML and PHP tags from a string.

Does Android have a way to escape html?

Answer (score 243, accepted):

The solutions in the answer linked to by @sparkymat generally require either regex - which is an error-prone approach - or installing a third-party library such as [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) or [jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html). A better solution on Android devices is just to make use of the Html.fromHtml() function:

```
public String stripHtml(String html) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
       return Html.fromHtml(html, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY).toString();
    } else {
       return Html.fromHtml(html).toString();
    }
}
```

This uses Android's built in Html parser to build a `Spanned` representation of the input html without any html tags. The "Span" markup is then stripped by converting the output back into a string.

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904739/html-fromhtml-deprecated-in-android-n), Html.fromHtml behaviour has changed since Android N. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) for more info.

Comment: Also please note `Html.fromHtml(String)` return an extended class of `CharSequence`. So you can use it directly with methods accepting `CharSequence` parameters, without calling `toString()`. Thanks Nick for great answer  :-)

Comment: You can also use `Html.escapeHtml(String)` if you just want to escape the tags without removing them.

Comment: I think Html.fromHtml(String) Method have limited sets of tag support

Comment: My html head has html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color:#484848;
}
h1, h2, h3 { font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif; margin: 0px; }
h1 { font-size: 1.2em; }
h2, h3 { font-size: 1.1em; }
a, a:link, a:visited { color: #2A5685;}
a:hover, a:active { color: #c61a1a; }
a.wiki-anchor { display: none; }
hr {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 0;
}
.footer {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-style: italic;
}
</style>
</head>                                       this is also not getting handled. Pls help

Comment: Note that `Html.fromHtml(html).toString();` removes multiple spaces which is not always a good choice.

Comment: Worked great, I had weird characters representing <img> tags and [replacing the character thanks to that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560045/android-getting-obj-using-textview-settextcharactersequence) and trimming the string did the rest of the job

Comment: Note that  `<br>` is replaced by `\n`.

Comment: deprecated for today

Comment: This code could be tidied up using `HtmlCompat`, and now with the adoption of Kotlin further shortened to `fun String.stripHtml() = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(this, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY).toString()`

Answer (score 15):

Sorry for the late post, but i think this might help for others,

**To just remove the html strips**

```
Html.fromHtml(htmltext).toString()
```

This way the html tag will be replaced with string, but the string willnot be formatted properly. Hence i did

```
Html.fromHtml(htmltext).toString().replaceAll("\n", "").trim()
```

This way i first replace with nextline with blankspace and removed blank space. Similarly you can remove others.

Comment: I needed 4 slashes. See Avis answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865393/java-replaceall-not-working-for-n-characters/18865424

Answer (score 12):

You can alternatively use `Html.escapeHtml(String)` if you are targeting API 16 or above.

For also targeting below API 16, you can instead use the below class by calling `HtmlUtils.escapeHtml(String)` which i simply pulled from the source of `Html.escapeHtml(String)`.

```
public class HtmlUtils {

    public static String escapeHtml(CharSequence text) {
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        withinStyle(out, text, 0, text.length());
        return out.toString();
    }

    private static void withinStyle(StringBuilder out, CharSequence text,
                                    int start, int end) {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            char c = text.charAt(i);

            if (c == '<') {
                out.append("&lt;");
            } else if (c == '>') {
                out.append("&gt;");
            } else if (c == '&') {
                out.append("&amp;");
            } else if (c >= 0xD800 && c <= 0xDFFF) {
                if (c < 0xDC00 && i + 1 < end) {
                    char d = text.charAt(i + 1);
                    if (d >= 0xDC00 && d <= 0xDFFF) {
                        i++;
                        int codepoint = 0x010000 | (int) c - 0xD800 << 10 | (int) d - 0xDC00;
                        out.append("&#").append(codepoint).append(";");
                    }
                }
            } else if (c > 0x7E || c < ' ') {
                out.append("&#").append((int) c).append(";");
            } else if (c == ' ') {
                while (i + 1 < end && text.charAt(i + 1) == ' ') {
                    out.append("&nbsp;");
                    i++;
                }

                out.append(' ');
            } else {
                out.append(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using this class which works fine.

Answer (score 4):

This is for new method alternative (API 16+):

```
android.text.Html.escapeHtml(your_html).toString();
```

Answer (score 4):

Html.fromHtml can be extremely slow for large html strings.

Here's how you can do it, easily and fast with jsoup:

Add this line to your gradle file:

```
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
```

Check what is the latest jsoup version here:
https://jsoup.org/download

Add this line to your code:

```
String text = Jsoup.parse(htmlStr).text();
```

Check this link here to learn how to preserve line breaks:

[How do I preserve line breaks when using jsoup to convert html to plain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640334/how-do-i-preserve-line-breaks-when-using-jsoup-to-convert-html-to-plain-text)

Answer (score 2):

```
 Spanned spanned;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            spanned = Html.fromHtml(textToShare, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
        } else {
            spanned = Html.fromHtml(textToShare);
        }
tv.setText(spanned.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

This is dead simple with [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/download)

```
public static String html2text(String html) {
   return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it has not been mentioned yet, the way to do this in a backwards compatible manner would be to use the [HtmlCompat utility class](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/text/HtmlCompat), and simply call (with 0 if you require no specific flags to be used)

```
HtmlCompat.from(inputString, 0).toString()
```

Under the hood it already does all the required api checks for you

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
   return Html.fromHtml(source, flags);
}
return Html.fromHtml(source);
```

So for for the input

```
<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">Click me!</a>
```

you will receive only the string 'Click me!' as output.