# Android :getting [OBJ] using Textview.SetText(characterSequence)

Tags: android, textview

I am getting [OBJ] displayed on the screen when I try to set a ImageSpan on a text View..it shows a /uFFFC unicode character instead of the image on the screen,i.e. a dotted box with  OBJ written inside it.

Comment: How do you expect anyone to help if you don't provide code of your current attempt?

Comment: fixed the issue..this was a side effect of creating a spannablebuilder buffer with null arguments in the constructor and then setting a particular span to that buffer object. This didnt give any compilation/runtime error.

Answer (score 28):

I faced the same problem, thus I just wanted to have the HTML stripped and just get the `String`.

The solution is probably not the most beautiful one, but still pretty pragmatical:

```
public CharSequence stripHtml(String s) {
    return Html.fromHtml(s).toString().replace('\n', (char) 32)
        .replace((char) 160, (char) 32).replace((char) 65532, (char) 32).trim();
}
```

This [OBJ] character seemed to be `(char) 65532`.

I had to display a very ugly RSS item's (HTML) description field in a `TextView` without formats. The hypertext contained a lot of WYSIWYG debris like `<p></p><p></p>`…