# Android: Emoticon Keyboard unable to get emoticon working on cursor adapter

Tags: android, baseadapter, android-cursoradapter, emoji

I am using [this Emoticon Keyboard](https://github.com/chiragjain/Emoticons-Keyboard). In the project author is using `BaseAdapter` ([link to code](https://github.com/chiragjain/Emoticons-Keyboard/blob/master/src/com/learn/testdifferentkeyboard/EmoticonsGridAdapter.java)) to render selected emoticons on list view. But for my application I am using `CursorAdapter` and this is the only difference.

Everything is working fine, I can display emoticon popup, select emoticons and they get displayed in `EditText`. The problem Iam having is that in my app, I have `Send` button and when I click on that, emoticons don't get rendered on the list view (using cursor adapter), naturally I must be missing something.

From the [main example activity](https://github.com/chiragjain/Emoticons-Keyboard/blob/master/src/com/learn/testdifferentkeyboard/MainActivity.java) of author, I suspect this is where emoticons are read and displayed in EditText:

```
@Override
public void keyClickedIndex(final String index) {

  ImageGetter imageGetter = new ImageGetter() {
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
      StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(index, ".");
      Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),
          emoticons[Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()) - 1]);
      d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
      return d;
    }
  };

  Spanned cs = Html.fromHtml("<img src ='" + index + "'/>", imageGetter,
      null);

  int cursorPosition = content.getSelectionStart();
  content.getText().insert(cursorPosition, cs);

}
```

I tried to do same thing in my cursor adapter but instead of emoticon, an strange character shows up, here is my code for my `CursorAdapter`:

```
public class MessageListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {    
    Context context;
    private Bitmap[] emoticons;
    private static final int NO_OF_EMOTICONS = 120;

    private void readEmoticons() {
        emoticons = new Bitmap[NO_OF_EMOTICONS];

        for (short i = 0; i < NO_OF_EMOTICONS; i++) {
            emoticons[i] = getImage((i + 1) + ".png");
        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public MessageListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor);
        this.context = context;
    }

    // bind views from db data for fields
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        final int index = cursor.getPosition();

        TextView lblDated = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.lblDatedMessageList);

        TextView lblTo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblToMessageList);

        lblDated.setText(Functions.getPrettyTime(cursor.getString(7)));

        String message = cursor.getString(5);

        readEmoticons();

        ImageGetter imageGetter = new ImageGetter() {
            public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("" + index, ".");

                Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(),
                        emoticons[Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()) - 1]);

                d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());

                return d;
            }
        };

        Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(message, imageGetter, null);
        lblTo.setText(spanned);

    }

    /**
     * For loading smileys from assets
     */
    private Bitmap getImage(String path) {
        AssetManager mngr = context.getAssets();
        InputStream in = null;

        try {
            in = mngr.open("emoticons/" + path);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Bitmap temp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, null);
        return temp;
    }
}
```

May be I am doing above wrong unlike author [with baseadapter](https://github.com/chiragjain/Emoticons-Keyboard/blob/master/src/com/learn/testdifferentkeyboard/EmoticonsGridAdapter.java). Or may be there should be some conversion between `Spanned` stuff...

So to simplify question, how do I **get emoticons rendered on `CursorAdapter` instead of `BaseAdapter` (unlike author)** ?

When you look at links with example code I have provided, you will know what I mean.

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there might be some error in saving spanned to database. Save spanned string using

```
String htmlString = Html.toHtml(spannedText);
```

and get back the same string from database using

```
Spanned cs = Html.fromHtml(htmlString, imageGetter, null);
```

and also,

remove `readEmoticons()` from `bindView(..)` and call it in constructor make `imageGetter` global and initialize it in constructor.

Hope it will solve your problem. Thanks...

Comment: No matter what I do in db always `&#65532;` is showing up :( something is wrong when saving to db via cursor adapter :( Every other text saves fine but an emoticon is always replaced by `&#65532;`. This is the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560045/android-getting-obj-using-textview-settextcharactersequence

Comment: I found the solution, I was not correctly saving html in db. Thanks it works now :)