# how to remove Html tag in android?

Tags: android, html, textview

I am creating one sample project in android. i am using sample rss feed.

In xml description coming like this,

```
 <![CDATA[
    <p>15&nbsp;Mar&nbsp;2012</p>
     <a href="http://newsonair.nic.in/full_news.asp?TOP2">
     <p style='FONT-SIZE: 12px; LINE-HEIGHT: 150%' align='justify'>
 <img style='FLOAT: left; MARGIN-RIGHT: 5px' height='100' width='100' src=http://www.newsonair.nic.in/writereaddata/news_pictures/PICNEWS1.jpg?
0.7055475></a><br/> 
Parliament was today disrupted over the issue of removal of Trinamool Congress&#39;s leader and the Railway Minister, Mr.Dinesh Trivedi from the Council of Ministers.</p><br clear="all" />
    ]]>
```

i want to display like this,

```
Parliament was today disrupted over the issue of removal of Trinamool Congress&#39;s leader and the Railway Minister, Mr.Dinesh Trivedi from the Council of Ministers.
```

can anyone tell the idea to do this.
thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to strip or escape html tags in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502759/how-to-strip-or-escape-html-tags-in-android)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
       html = html.replaceAll("<(.*?)\\>"," ");//Removes all items in brackets
       html = html.replaceAll("<(.*?)\\\n"," ");//Must be undeneath
       html = html.replaceFirst("(.*?)\\>", " ");//Removes any connected item to the last bracket
       html = html.replaceAll("&nbsp;"," ");
       html = html.replaceAll("&amp;"," ");
```

Here is a piece of my code.

Comment: My code works for anything that is in brackets mine is slightly larger because I find it more efficient than a json parser.

Comment: What does it end with and starts with? Can you post the line of the code?

Comment: Put this in another question regarding regex on this type I will give an answer there. This little commentbox is not a good place to put an answer on.

Comment: Pattern and matcher will get you the last piece if you the Imajh

Comment: I would recoomend using @waqaslam 's sollution since this method is really slow compared to HTML.fromHtml

Answer (score 38):

do it as below:

```
String plain = Html.fromHtml("your_html_string").toString();
```

Comment: I am not able to use above method for my json parsing

Comment: Yes i am getting json response in html form in my string type variable

Comment: Actually getting json in html format is incorrect. You need to fix your web-service to return pure json format. Otherwise its an overkill on the mobile platform.

Comment: I am getting this json output <p><span style=\"line-height: 1.3em;\">Notre équipe se consacre à toutes les difficultés rencontrées par les entreprises et leurs dirigeants, ainsi que les cadres, sur le plan professionnel et personnel. Nous intervenons également auprès des particuliers, et pour tous types de litiges commerciaux et immobiliers de manière générale.</span></p>\r\n

Comment: this is not json. it is plain html code. Like i said, you need to configure you web-server to reutrn valid json string response instead of html.

Comment: Actually its working after convert above json with below code  like "replaceAll("s/<(.*?)>//g","");"

Comment: So will it be create problem afterwords or it will work fine?

Comment: i have a question in stackoverflow its has to do it this, but i have no answer to it yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22109964/how-to-remove-html-tags-from-a-json-data-in-android?noredirect=1#comment33540717_22109964

Comment: This doesn't create the same result as _removing the HTML tags_. This simply converts the HTML text to plain text. An example of the difference can be seen if the HTML texts contains a `<p>` tag. Removing the HTML tags should result in having no line break, but the approach shown in this answer will have a line break. Depending on the desired result, this can be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

This might work:

```
myHtmlString.replaceAll("s/<(.*?)>//g","");
```

Or

```
Html.fromHtml(htmlSrc).toString();
```

But there can be some bugs on the last one.

Comment: First replaceAll("s/<(.*?)>//g",""); doesn't work for me.