# java replaceAll not working for \n characters

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I have a string like this: `John \n Barber` now I want to replace \n with actual new line character so it will become

`John`

Barber

this is my code for this

```
replaceAll("\\n", "\n");
```

but it is not working and giving me same string `John \n Barber`

Comment: i think use replaceAll("\\\\n","\\n");

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to do:

```
replaceAll("\\\\n", "\n");
```

The `replaceAll` method expects a regex in its first argument. When passing 2 `\` in java string you actually pass one. The problem is that `\` is an escape char also in regex so the regex for `\n` is actualy `\\n` so you need to put an extra `\` twice.

Answer (score 4):

Since `\n` (or even the raw new line character U+000A) in regex is interpreted as new line character, you need `\\n` (escape the `\`) to specify slash `\` followed by `n`.

That is from the regex engine's perspective.

From the compiler's perspective, in Java literal string, you need to escape `\`, so we add another layer of escaping:

```
String output = inputString.replaceAll("\\\\n", "\n");
//                                      \\n      U+000A
```

Comment: when i tried this way its working,String x="x\ny";
     String y=x.replaceAll("\\n", "\n");
     System.out.println(y);

Comment: @javaBeginner: Your original string contains the new line already.

Comment: isnt this same way that of OP?

Comment: @javaBeginner: No. OP's raw string contains a ``\`` followed by `n`, which means in Java literal, it would be `"something\\nsomething"`

Comment: I am confused,still +1 for this answer

Comment: @javaBeginner: OP's string contains ``\`` followed by an `n`. That is the difference here. If you want to make it clear, try to write a program that take input from command prompt, and use the replaceAll on it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape `\` character. So try

```
replaceAll("\\\\n", "\n");
```

Answer (score 3):

**replaceAll** is using Regular Expressions, you can use **replace** which will also replace all '\n':

```
replace("\\\\n", "\n");
```