# HTML String tags are not replaced (Android)

Tags: android, html, replace, textview

I have the following piece of HTML:

```
<p>Bla bla bla...</p>
<p><strong>4. others</strong></p>
<p> </p>
```

It contains a random `<p> </p>` tag combination which needs to be filtered out in my Android app. I'm using the following Java code for it:

```
String html = object.get("Content").toString(); // this is the HTML
html = html.replace("<p> </p>", "");
html = html.replace("<p></p>", "");
html = html.replace("<p><span></span></p>", "");
content.setText(Html.fromHtml(html));
```

However, when I debug and put a break point on the replace functions, it doesn't replace the strings. Now I have useless `<p>` tags which I don't want. How do I solve this?

Comment: Please try to transform your html string to lower case so your replace logic is not case sensitive. It can be possible that this is the problem, because HTML tags are generally defined and handled in upper case by most parsers.

Comment: Did not help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502759/how-to-strip-or-escape-html-tags-in-android?

Comment: Your replacement criteria are wrong, unless you convert them to `regular expressions`

Comment: I added "html = html.toLowerCase();" which didn't help unfortunately. Notice that I'm only trying to replace the random tags where it's just tag+space+tag. Not all tags like in Mr. Sandy's answer, it's only the tags with no content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It contains a random 



 tag combination which needs to be filtered out in my Android app. 
You need to **replace it separately**. Because *replace()* function works **case-sensitive** and **sequential strings**.
So, Use below code

```
String html = object.get("Content").toString().trim(); // this is the HTML
html = html.replace("<p>", "");
html = html.replace("</p>", "");
html = html.replace("<span>", "");
html = html.replace("</span>", "");
content.setText(Html.fromHtml(html));
```

instead of your *joint* string in *replace()*

```
String html = object.get("Content").toString(); // this is the HTML
html = html.replace("<p> </p>", "");
html = html.replace("<p></p>", "");
html = html.replace("<p><span></span></p>", "");
content.setText(Html.fromHtml(html));
```

You get result as per you want.

**Note**: But, remember that anytime you want to replace any *character/string* than just replace it *sequential* with *case-sensitive*. because It gives you *exact result*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not exactly what I mean. I want to leave all the tags as how they are, unless it's the exact combination where there's an starting and a closing tag without any content. All the tags which do contain content, should just stay where they are. Your solution removes all the tags, even when there's content inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it in wrong way.

**Correct way:**
 1. Use StringBuffer instead of String.
 2. Find index of < and put it in a variable say int startIdx
 3. Find index of > and put it in a variable say int endIdx
 4. then use delete() of StringBuffer and specify this startIdx and endIdx to delete HTML tag.

This will remove all HTML code from your string.

**Ok so as per your comment, this is how you do it**

```
String replaceThis="<p></p>";
int len = replaceThis.length();
StringBuffer buff="your html string from which you want to replace";
int i;
while((i = buff.indexOf(replaceThis)!=-1)
{
    buff.delete(i,len-1);
}
```

Comment: That's not what I want. I only want EXACTLY this combination: "<p></p>". Because it creates random blank lines. All the other tags are perfectly fine and can stay where they are. It's that specific pattern