# Extract 2 substring in different languages from string

Tags: string, rss, hebrew

I have a string that contains a description of an RSS item I parsed.
This string contains the description(in Hebrew), an image URL and a few other characters i don't need.

I'm looking for a way to extract the description and URL into 2 new strings.

As far as the URL goes, I've found a solution that works fine for me.
However, since the location and length of the description part within the parent is unknown, I'm kinda stuck with that...

** An idea i have and trying to figure out how to code correctly:

```
String parent;
for (int i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
char currentChar = parent.charAt(i);
// check if the Char is in Hebrew and remove any other Char
}
```

However this idea is problematic,
since that in addition to Hebrew,
I also need to save multi language chars(i.e numbers, periods, commas, quotes and others).

Here are a few examples of the string:
(it is partly in Hebrew, so i apologize if it's unreadable)

```
"במשטרה חושדים כי פיודור בייז'ניריי הצליח לרצוח ולאנוס ללא חשדות נגדו<p><img src=\"http:\/\/images.nana10.co.il\/upload\/mediastock\/img\/11\/0\/258\/258180.jpg\" alt=\"\" title=\"\"\/><\/p>

<p style=\"direction:rtl; clear:both\">\t\t\t <a href=\"http:\/\/news.walla.co.il\/item\/2956715\"> <img hspace=5 border=0 align=\"right\" src=\"http:\/\/msc.wcdn.co.il\/archive\/2132766-18.jpg\" \/>  <\/a> <BR> \n\t\t\tלוחמי משמר הגבול מצאו במהלך סיור באחת משכונות מזרח ירושלים כלב פצוע שעורר את חשדם. הם פינו את הכלב לטיפול במרפאה וטרינרית שם התברר כי הוא נגנב למטרת שימוש בקרבות כלבים. בעלי הכלב: \"אנחנו עדיין לא מעכלים שהוא חזר אלינו\"<\/p>

"הערב בחדשות: גילויים חדשים סביב מעצרו של מי שבמשטרה מכנים \"הרוצח הסדרתי\"; במרחק נגיעה מחיזבאללה - כתבנו במוצב הרגיש בצפון; ניצחונות סוחפים לטראמפ וקלינטון; בניגוד לחוק: בתי אבות מסרבים לקבל אליהם נשא של נגיף ה- HIV ; חשופים בדרכים: פרצת אבטחה מאפשרת לעקוב אחריכם כשאתם נוהגים עם וויז. כיצד מתגוננים?<p><img src='http:\/\/img.mako.co.il\/2016\/04\/28\/638671_A.jpg'\/><\/p>

גרושתו של פיודור בייז'נרי: \"ישנו באותה מיטה, הוא לא עשה את זה\"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: So I figured out that all I had to do is strip all HTML components from the string and that's it.

Just use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7389663/6252096)!