# Format html tag to a string java

Tags: java, html, string, listview, string-formatting

I need help
I have a string like this

```
String myString = "The accuracy of a potentiometer (pH meter) is
                   &#177;0.1 mV. A solution contains 1x10<SUP>-4<\/SUP> mol\/L Cl
                   <SUP>-<\/SUP> and 1x10<SUP>-3<\/SUP> mol\/L Ca<SUP>2+<\/SUP>. 
                   What is the error in concentration to be expected when measuring
                   these ions with a chloride or a calcium ion selective electrode? 
                   <TABLE BORDER=0 ALIGN=CENTER> <TR><TD>    <\/TD><TD>&nbsp;<\/TD><TD>
                   <\/TD><\/TR><\/TABLE>";
```

I have to show this string in a listView but obviously when I print it there are these html tags.

I already tried to get rid of the tags but if so I lost informations (like -4 as superscipt). 
I'd like to know if it is possible to format the string in a proper way.

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I have partially solved by using Html.fromHtml(String)

```
public String processString(String html) {
    Spanned spanned;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        spanned = Html.fromHtml(html, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
    } else {
        spanned = Html.fromHtml(html);
    }
    return spanned.toString();
}
```

Now the problem is that the  tag is displayed like an obj icon
[image] 
and i don't know how to visualize them.

Is it possible?

Comment: Apache commons has a function that escapes html aka converts characters to HTML entities. See function escapeHtml: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html

Comment: You could run this through an HTML reader. Though it isn't a complete document. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLDocument.HTMLReader.html

Comment: Btw. Are you talking about an android ListView? in that case this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502759/how-to-strip-or-escape-html-tags-in-android

Comment: @DejaVuSansMono Sorry but I don't know how to do it. Can you explain better how to use it please?

Answer (score 0):

If you heal the html, it will be rendered fine by many Swing components, without assistance:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Se0124 extends JFrame
{
    String myString = "<html>" +
                   "The accuracy of a potentiometer (pH meter) is" +
                   "&#177;0.1 mV. A solution contains 1x10<SUP>-4</SUP> mol/L Cl" +
                   "<SUP>-</SUP> and 1x10<SUP>-3</SUP> mol/L Ca<SUP>2+</SUP>." +
                   "What is the error in concentration to be expected when measuring" +
                   "these ions with a chloride or a calcium ion selective electrode?" +
                   "</html>";

    public Se0124 ()
    {
        super ("Se0124");
        JPanel mainpanel = new JPanel ();
        mainpanel.setLayout (new BorderLayout ());
        this.getContentPane ().add (mainpanel);

        JLabel jl = new JLabel (myString);
        mainpanel.add (jl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize (400, 400);
        setLocation (100, 100);
        setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible (true);
    }

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Se0124 ();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have removed the trailing , which looks empty. Then I capsulated it in  tags. And I removed the backslashes from the slashes.

This can be done by regular expressions. Now SUP and SUB are rendered fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `String.replaceAll` method to replace all occurrences of a specified regular expression.

Example

```java
myString = myString.replaceAll("<\\s*.+?>", "");
```

Output (I've added new lines, to provide readablity)

```
The accuracy of a potentiometer (pH meter) is
&#177;0.1 mV. A solution contains 1x10-4 mol/L Cl
- and 1x10-3 mol/L Ca2+.
What is the error in concentration to be expected when measuring
these ions with a chloride or a calcium ion selective electrode?
     &nbsp;
```

In regard to the entity value, `&#177;`, this is a trivial task.

You *could* create a method to capture the value, and parse it to it's Unicode equivalent, although not all entities use the Unicode value, sometimes it's a literal, such as "amp", or "lt".

Many people choose to use the Apache Commons Text library, to decode entities.

[StringEscapeUtils (Apache Commons Text 1.10.0 API)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4-java.lang.String-)