# How to remove tags/ special letters while fetching data from Json to an android app?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

**I am getting the JSON responses like this ->**

[image]

[image]

Here you can check out the complete JSON response ->
https://api.nasa.gov/techtransfer/patent/?engine&api_key=DEMO_KEY

Also this is my data class look like ->

```
          @Parcelize
             data class Patent(
             val count: Int,
             val page: Int,
             val perpage: Int,
             val results: List<List<String>>,
             val total: Int
                 ) : Parcelable
```

I parsed data using Retrofit.

**Here's the interface->**

```
    interface NasaInterface {

@GET("techtransfer/patent/?telescope&api_key=${API_KEY}")
fun getNasaPatents(): Call<Patent>   }
              
     
        object NasaService {
     
         val nasaInterface: NasaInterface

         init {
         val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                  .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                  .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                  .build()

    nasaInterface = retrofit.create(NasaInterface::class.java)
}   }
```

**And here's the function of getting the data ->**

```
                private fun callingAdapter() {
    val nasaPatents = NasaService.nasaInterface.getNasaPatents()

    nasaPatents.enqueue(object : Callback<Patent>, iPostAdapter {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<Patent>, response: Response<Patent>) {
            val nasaPatentsi = response.body()

            if (nasaPatentsi != null) {

                adapter = PatentAdapter(this@MainFragment, nasaPatentsi, this)
                recyclerViewItems!!.adapter = adapter
            }

        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<Patent>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d("pERROR", "$t , $call")
            progressLoaderAdp!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        }
```

I want to remove those tags like "span class..." .
When you look at that JSON response, you will see that all important stuff coming in app from Result Key. I wonder if we can remove those tags from values of Result key?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502759/how-to-strip-or-escape-html-tags-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing the HTML code, I would go for setting the text as HTML.

```
Html.fromHtml("NASA TEXT WITH HTML", flag)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer I have no experience in html would you please elaborate or share any helpful resource to do the same. Also I have a question what if the JSON got updated  or changes from nasa? your solution will still work?

Comment: There are some HTML tags that are not supported by android, here you can find the complete list. 
https://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html

The solution I purpose is because you are trying to set an HTML text on a textview. The other option is to remove all the HTML tags, but for that, you'll need to use regex expressions, it isn't a good idea. 

If NASA updates the text with more HTML tags, and these tags are not supported (like a list), you'll see a plain text instead of, for example, a list.

Comment: Man still I am not getting how to remove this. I had mailed to NASA aswell. See here I uploaded this on playstore (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kushalsharma.nasawalli ) and I have to solve this error as soon as possible.

Comment: Can you paste the fragment of code where you are setting the text to texview?

Comment: Check now I had added.

Comment: The key class is PatentAdapter, which is where you are setting the text to textview.